# Unable to start a service

Tags: service, wix

I have a C# application using a WiX bootstrapper setup. This setup install SQL Server and my application. This application is an old application with a Custom Service : `public partial class MyCustomService : System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase`.

Previously, this service was installed with a Windows Installer (`System.Configuration.Install.Installer`). I modified the project to use WiX. Now the service should start like this :

```
<Component Id="MyCustomService" Guid="{THE-GUID}" KeyPath="yes">        
  <!-- service will need to be installed under Local Service -->

  <ServiceInstall
    Id="MyCustomService"
    Type="ownProcess"
    Vital="yes"
    Name="MyCustomService"
    DisplayName="My Custom Service"
    Description="Service Custom"
    Start="auto"
    Account="NT AUTHORITY\LocalService"
    ErrorControl="normal"/>
  <ServiceControl Id="MyCustomService_Start" Name="MyCustomService" Start="install" Wait="no" />
  <ServiceControl Id="MyCustomService_Stop" Name="MyCustomService" Stop="both" Wait="yes" Remove="uninstall" /> />
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\MyCustomService" ForceCreateOnInstall="yes" ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes">
      <RegistryValue Type="expandable"/>
    </RegistryKey>
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\MyCustomService" ForceCreateOnInstall="yes" ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes">
      <RegistryValue Type="expandable"/>
    </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

EDIT :

I finally passed the exception. The service try to start but stop just after. I saw in the log event : "Access to registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\MyCustomService' has been refused.

Is there a way to set rights for all when I create the registry key ?

Comment: This is the same as your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467984/unable-to-start-service-with-wix-installer/40471973#40471973 and you indicated it was corrected. Does this mine it was not corrected?

Comment: The problem was resolve on a PC but I tried in another one and the Service doesn't start. I've installed all the dlls presents in the first PC but it didn't fix the problem. Here I try to identify what can be missing.

Comment: Is it possible for you to execute the MSI? If yes, Could you try to run your MSI in command line to give us the logs:  `msiexec.exe /i c:\PathToYourMsi\YourMsi.msi /L*vx c:\PathToYourLog.txt`